# How to allow custom HTML tags in the CKEditor 5 of TYPO3 12?

Tags: typo3, ckeditor5, typo3-12.x

According to the [changelog](https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/main/en-us//Changelog/12.0/Feature-96874-CKEditor5.html#configuration-options), the CKEditor 5 plugin "[GeneralHTMLSupport](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/html/general-html-support.html)" is available in TYPO3 12. I guess it can be activated in the own editor configuration (yaml):

```
imports:
  - { resource: 'EXT:rte_ckeditor/Configuration/RTE/Processing.yaml' }
  - { resource: 'EXT:rte_ckeditor/Configuration/RTE/Editor/Base.yaml' }
  - { resource: 'EXT:rte_ckeditor/Configuration/RTE/Editor/Plugins.yaml' }

editor:
  config:
    ???
```

Unfortunately, the examples from the CKEditor 5 documentary, like …

```
htmlSupport: {
    allow: [
        {
            name: 'div',
            classes: true
        }
    ]
}
```

… does not work here.

How can I allow `<div class="xyz">…</div>` in the RTE, for example?

Addendum:
As I have just learned, it cannot work at all yet due to the bug https://forge.typo3.org/issues/100861. Nevertheless, I would be interested to know how to configure it after the bug fix is implemented.

Comment: Actually v12.4.7 should include the options as the patch was just yesterday applied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As David mentioned in the comment above, it now works since TYPO3 version 12.4.7. [as described in the docu](https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-rte-ckeditor/12.4/en-us/Configuration/Examples.html#how-do-i-allow-a-specific-tag):

*EXT:my_sitepackage/Configuration/RTE/MyPreset.yaml*

```
# Allow the <iframe> tag with all attributes, all classes and all styles:
RTE:
  config:
    htmlSupport:
      allow:
        - { name: 'iframe', attributes: true, classes: true, styles: true }
```